# Firebase-core 17.0 dependency conflicts with Appcompat-v7

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, androidx

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not
>   be combined but found
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support',
>   myArtifactId='slidingpanelayout', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'} and
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.versionedparcelable',
>   myArtifactId='versionedparcelable', myVersion='1.0.0',
>   myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies
>   less... (Ctrl+F1)  Inspection info:There are some combinations of
>   libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead
>   to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the
>   Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in
>   particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

That error is showing on `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` when i use `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'`

Answer (score 2):

Firebase migrated to `androidx` with latest release, so you should either use androidx in your project or simply use older version, for example:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

About migrating to androidx: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

Check the [release notes of firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) libraries:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  Service        |  Gradle dependency                        |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Firebase Core   | com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

> This release is a **MAJOR** version update and includes breaking changes.
>   **With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.**
>   **The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:**

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to `v3.2.1` or later.
- Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to `28` or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).